# Wine Gecko not installing

Tags: 16.04, wine

Im using Ubuntu 16.04.1
When I try to install some programs Im getting this error

> Wine could not find a Gecko Package which is needed for applications embedding HTML to work properly. Wine can automatically download and install it for now.

When I click Install... It is trying to Download it... But at some point it is sticking always.

I also tried to install it from here  https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko 
I downloaded the .msi file But Wine is unable to install that msi file...

I also tried with

```
wine msiexec /i wine_gecko-2.47-x86_64.msi
```

But getting this error -

```
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_32" failed to start: 1053
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\mscorsvw.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\mscorsvw.exe" failed, status c0000135
err:service:service_send_command service protocol error - failed to write pipe!
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64" failed to start: 1053
```

I also Tried copying the file to /usr/share/wine/gecko But When I try to install the program It is again saying Wine could not find a Gecko Package...

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try running the msiexec command for both the x86_64 and x86 versions of the file. I understand that you do need both.

Answer (score 0):

[Wine Gecko](https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko) comes "bundled" as part of their IE packages. Installing some flavour of IE should bring Gecko with it.

One of the apps I run under WINE uses .chm files a lot, and they weren't rendering (just blank). When I ran the file with `wine hh file.chm` in the terminal, this was the error message I got:

`Could not load wine-gecko. ...`

I used `winetricks` to install IE8 into my Wine space, and then the .chm files loaded perfectly -- error gone.